# SSAI - Server side ad insertion : How do you monetize it

Tags: cdn, vast

SSAI is the stitching of ads on the server side. So a user would get one video stream containing the actual video and the ad.

But how are impression pixels handled in SSAI? The client still would need to send these pixels when the view has clicked on the ad and so on?

Answer (score 0):

Typically pixels are fired on the server and some are still fired client-side using the client-side SDKs of your SSAI vendor.

Comment: Please elaborate your answer.